# spanish accented characters inside a JavaFX text field

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, textfield

I'm developing an application in Spanish, but in the menus and the text I have to put accented characters but this does not display correctly when I run the application.

For a example, in the code it is

```
final MenuItem noEffects = new MenuItem("reiniciar selección");
```

but after running the application it is displayed as

> reiniciar selecci?n

How can I display the Spanish text correctly?

Edit:

this is a test code (same issue in the main code)

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;  
import javafx.scene.Parent;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hóla mundo");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How old is your system? What OS are you rinning? What Java and JavaFX distributions are you using? What IDE are you using?

Comment: is windows 7, JDK 1.8.0_45, and the IDE es intellij IDEA 14.1.3

Comment: Are you using any font different from the default one?

Comment: Looks good! I just tried your setup on my Window 7, jkd8u45 (includes latest javafx which is 8), using the eclipse IDE and had no issues! Why don't you paste working your code (by editing and adding it to your post) to inspect. It may also be a missing system font problem, but your setup and intellij should protect you from that.

Comment: Have you tried with Scene Builder? Create a simple FXML file, add some pane and then add a `Text` node with the same string, and see if still happens.

Comment: i'm gonna paste the code. for the other hand with scene builder will not work for me, because the text going to have changes while program is running

Comment: Anyway, try it with Scene Builder and check it with some string that is failing in your code. Also try to load a different font and check if that works.

Comment: What is the encoding of your .java file? Does the *compiler* use this same encoding? Simple experiment to test: compile a simple class with a main method that writes this string to a file. Can you read that file?

Comment: José: in Scene Builder i try and works, but when i reload the string from the code happen again.Nikos, where i can find the encoding of each one, i'm gonna to create the file

Comment: Nikos: I create a txt file but the string that i try to save don't show when I open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from OP and edited to remove spelling mistakes and improve formatting. Removed the answer from there and put it here as CW.

EDIT: Finally I solved this issue, I had to configure the encoding format in IntelliJ, which is made doing the following steps:

1. Go to File > Other Settings > Default Settings
2. There in the left panel select Edit > File encoding
3. On the right side of the window select "windows-1252" for encoding in IDE Encoding, Project Encoding and Default encoding for properties file.